# How can I merge three variables into one variable that represents the merged variables separated by a comma?

Tags: r, variables, merge

I have three variables: Year, Month, and Day. How can I merge them into one variable ("Date") so that the variable is represented as such:
yyyy-mm-dd

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: Have you tried `paste`?

Comment: Please add example data to your question, which contain a minimal reproducible example, e. g. `data <- data.frame(Y = "2010", M = "12", D = "31")` and how exactly your expected result should look alike. It is difficult to find an exact answer otherwise.

Comment: `tidyr::unite(df, "Date", Y:D, sep = "-")` if you don't want to keep the original columns

Answer (score 0):

Below we create year-month-day character strings, yyyy-mm-dd character strings (similar except one digit month and day are zero padded out to 2 digits) and Date class.  The last one prints out as yyyy-mm-dd and can be manipulated in ways that character strings can't, for example adding one to a Date class object gives the next day.

First we set up some sample input:

```
year <- c(2017, 2015, 2014)
month <- c(3, 1, 10)
day <- c(15, 9, 25)
```

**convert to year-month-day character string**  This is not quite yyyy-mm-dd since 1 digit months and days are not zero padded to 2 digits:

```
paste(year, month, day, sep = "-")
## [1] "2017-3-15"  "2015-1-9"   "2014-10-25"
```

**convert to Date class** It prints on console as yyyy-mm-dd.  Two alternatives:

```
as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))
## [1] "2017-03-15" "2015-01-09" "2014-10-25"

as.Date(ISOdate(year, month, day))
## [1] "2017-03-15" "2015-01-09" "2014-10-25"
```

**convert to character string yyyy-mm-dd**  In this case 1 digit month and day are zero padded out to 2 characters.  Two alternatives:

```
as.character(as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-")))
## [1] "2017-03-15" "2015-01-09" "2014-10-25"

sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day)
## [1] "2017-03-15" "2015-01-09" "2014-10-25"
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you merge three variables into one variable?

Consider two methods:

1. Old school
2. With `dplyr`, `lubridate`, and data frames

And consider the data **types.** You can have:

1. Number or character
2. `Date` or `POSIXct` final type

#### Old School Method

The old school method is straightforward. I assume you are using **vectors** or **lists** and don't know data frames yet. Let's take your data, force it to a standardized, unambiguous format, and concatenate the data.

```
> y <- 2012:2015
> y
[1] 2012 2013 2014 2015
> m <- 1:4
> m
[1] 1 2 3 4
> d <- 10:13
> d
[1] 10 11 12 13
```

Use `as.numeric` if you want to be safe and convert everything to the same format before concatenation. If you get any `NA` values you will need to handle them with the `is.na` function and provide a default value.

Use `paste` with the `sep` separator value set to your delimiter, in this case, the hyphen.

```
> paste(y,m,d, sep = '-')
[1] "2012-1-10" "2013-2-11" "2014-3-12" "2015-4-13"
```

#### Dataframe / Dplyr / Lubridate Way

```html
> df <- data.frame(year = y, mon = m, day = d)
> df
  year mon day
1 2012   1  10
2 2013   2  11
3 2014   3  12
4 2015   4  13
```

Below I do the following:

1. Take the `df` object
2. Create a new variable name `Date`
3. Concatenate the numeric variables `y`, `m`, and `d` with a `-` separator
4. Convert the string literal into a `Date` format with `ymd()`

```html
> df %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(
          paste(y,m,d, sep = '-')
                )
        )
  year mon day       Date
1 2012   1  10 2012-01-10
2 2013   2  11 2013-02-11
3 2014   3  12 2014-03-12
4 2015   4  13 2015-04-13
```